# Cant get correct output of one line

Tags: c, printf, output

i made this program that generates the rolls of two dice adds them up and then displays how many tries it took to do this. My problem is the program adds them all up correctly it just doesnt seem to be able to print how many tries it took to successfully reach the total you enter at the start. Example of the expected output i want is as follows.

```
  Dice Thrower
  ============
  Total sought : 7
  Result of throw 1 : 4 + 4
  Result of throw 2 : 1 + 4
  Result of throw 3 : 2 + 6
  Result of throw 4 : 1 + 1
  Result of throw 5 : 4 + 3
  You got your total in 5 throws!
```

Here is my code.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <time.h>

   int validator();      //Function to validate
   void clear(void);     //Clear function

   int main() {

    int i=0,counter = 0, input, SUM, random1, random2;  //Variables


    printf("Dice Thrower\n");         //Print statements
    printf("============\n");
    printf("Total sought : ");
    input = validator();              //Call Function Validator

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 2; SUM!= input; i++)    //For Loop for random dice throws

    {

            random1 = rand()%6+1;
            random2 = rand()%6+1;
            SUM = random1 + random2;
            counter++;
            printf("Result of throw %d : %d + %d\n", counter, random1, random2);

      if (SUM == i)

           {

           printf("You got your total in %d throws!\n", counter);        //Print                   statement for final total

           }
    }
    return 0;
}        

  int validator()                       //Validator function

  {

   int tries = 1, boss, returnvalue;
  char k;

  do{

boss =  scanf("%d%c", &returnvalue,&k);

    if (boss == 0)
    {

    printf ("Invalid input, Try again : ");
    clear();
    }

    else if(returnvalue >= 13 || returnvalue <= 1)

           {

           printf("Invalid integer entered, please enter an integer greater than or equal to 2 and less than or equal to 12 : ");

           }

    else if(k != '\n')

           {

           printf("Trailing characters present, reenter : ");
           clear();
           }

    else
           {

           tries = 0;

           }

} while ( tries == 1);

    return returnvalue;

      }

      void clear (void) {                //Clear function

      while ( getchar() != '\n' );

      }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change  this condition `if (SUM == i)` as below:

```
    if (SUM == input)
```

As you want to compare the `SUM` against the `input`.